# `NSFetchedResultsController` fetched data changes with and without save when using predicate

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

`NSFetchedResultsCotroller` behaves strangely when using predicate. The following code prints the output:

```
Rows - 0
```

But when I comment out `[self saveContext]` (the first one) the output becomes:

```
Rows - 1
```

Removing the predicate (`query.predicate`) fixes things and the output is always:

```
Rows - 1
```

I suspect it has something to do with how `NULL` is compared in memory vs in DB query. Any idea what is actually going on?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSError *error;

    // Deletes persistent store coordinator behind the scene

    // Create an empty entity with the optional fields attr1 (string) and attr2 (date)
    Entity *e = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [self saveContext]; // <---------------- Code to comment out

    // Setup fetched results controller
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(attr1 != %@) AND (attr2 != %@)", @"", [NSDate new], nil];

    NSFetchRequest *query = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
    query.predicate = pred;
    query.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"attr1" ascending:NO]];

    frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:query managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    frc.delegate = self;
    [frc performFetch:&error];

    // Output #1
    NSLog(@"Rows - %ld", frc.fetchedObjects.count);

    [self saveContext];

    return YES;
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"Rows - %ld (Update)", controller.fetchedObjects.count);
}
```

**Edit**:

Modifying the predicate seems to fix it. Still no idea why:

```
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((attr1 = NULL) OR (attr1 != %@)) AND ((attr2 = NULL) OR (attr2 != %@))", @"", date];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would suspect it has to do with your predicate. I think the behavior of `nil` as the substitution object is unpredictable. You can either use `NULL` or `nil` in the format string itself or a real object that represents null, i.e. `[NSNull null]`. If you try this, maybe your original predicate will also work.

But there is something else going on. Perhaps your entity has some default values that make the predicate fail, which could explain why the save could change the fetch result under certain circumstances. Also, it is not clear what the content of the `saveContext` method is.

Also, not that `[NSDate new]` produces a date that is accurate to 1/10000th of a second, so this part of the predicate should always return `true`.

Comment: `saveContext` is the default code generated by XCode for CoreData projects. No default values. In my real code I use `<` this is just a toy example. I also suspect that `nil` substitution is to blame but couldn't find any documentation of it. I think the DB query is different than the in-memory object update notifications and merges.

Comment: Here is the [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html). You should accept the answer.

Comment: Can you please direct me to the part when it speak about `nil` substitution or implies it?

Comment: >@"attributeName == %@"
This predicate checks whether the value of the key attributeName is the same as the value of the object %@ that is supplied at runtime as an argument to predicateWithFormat:. Note that %@ can be a placeholder for any object whose description is valid in the predicate, such as an instance of NSDate, NSNumber, NSDecimalNumber, or NSString.

Comment: Yeah, well they should have stated it more clearly or at least raise an exception when `nil` is used.